# 18.04: How to draw on an application on the desktop

Tags: 18.04, desktop-background

I would like to create an application similar to the Windows Open Source app [Rainmeter](https://www.rainmeter.net/) that allows me to run programs and widgets on the desktop (below all other applications and toolbars, but above the background) I'm sure there is a way to do this, but I can't seem to find the right words and search terms to get any useful results.

How do I do this on Ubuntu 18.04?

Is there an application stack in Linux (like in Windows)? If so, how do I hook into it?

I read up on how to do this once using the win32 api, but can't seem to find that tutorial again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications can set their window properties. One of the properties would be "below", ensuring the window (eventually without decorations) remains below any other window, another one, "sticky" would ensure the window shows up on any desktop.

See `man wmctl` for information about a bash tool that allows to change such settings for existing windows from the terminal. In principle, it is of course the application itself that needs to interact with the window manager.

How you do this, depends on the programing language you use. Window managers tend to adhere to the common freedesktop.org specifications. Specifications on how to interact with windows can be found [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html).

For specific answers connected to the programming language you use, you will have a higher chance of getting good specific help on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: This will help, thank you!